# grepl for any string allowed

Tags: r, grepl

I am building a grepl command is fed by a function parameter. I'd like to skip the grep command if it's not needed. I could do this with control statements, but I would like to pass a value that returns all strings.

```
some_sub <- function(data, descr="*.*"){
     return(data %>% filter(grepl(descr, description)))
}
```

I'd like to have the following working:

```
some_sub(data, "Cabbage")
some_sub(data) # returns everything
```

where data

```
data <- structure(list(description = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
                                   .Label = c("Cabbage","Carrot"), 
                                   class = "factor"), 
           weight = c(12L, 9L, 7L, 15L)), 
      class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to just use `.` (as it is a metacharacter for any character) as the default match for `descr` parameter

Added one more paramet `colNm` to generalize a bit more

If there are blanks (`""`) and want to match those, it may be better to have `*` as the default

```
some_sub <- function(data, colNm, descr="."){
 colNm <- enquo(colNm)
 data %>%
      filter(grepl(descr, !!colNm))
} 

some_sub(iris, Species, "setosa")
some_sub(iris, Species)
```

---

Using OP' data

```
some_sub(data, description, "Cabbage")
#  description weight
#1     Cabbage     12
#2     Cabbage      9
#3     Cabbage     15

some_sub(data, description)
#  description weight
#1     Cabbage     12
#2     Cabbage      9
#3      Carrot      7
#4     Cabbage     15
```